# JS Audio onended not triggering when audio ends

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I'm trying to get a function to fire when the audio has ended. I am using this function to create the sound.

```
function sound(src,volume,repeat) {
    volume = volume || 1
    repeat = repeat || false;
    this.sound = document.createElement("audio");
    this.sound.volume = volume;
    this.sound.src = src;
    this.sound.setAttribute("preload", "");
    this.sound.setAttribute("class", "gamesound");
    if(repeat)this.sound.setAttribute("loop","");
    this.sound.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(this.sound);
    this.play = function(){
        this.sound.play();
    }
    this.stop = function(){
        this.sound.pause();
    }
    this.pause = function(){
        this.sound.pause();
    }
    this.onend = function (s){
         this.sound.onended = s;                
    }
    this.load = function(){
        this.sound.load();
    }
    this.currentTime = function (t){
        this.sound.currentTime = t;
    }
}
```

So it can be used like this

```
var song = new sound("sound.mp3",0.2,true);
song.ended(function(){
    alert("ended");
})
```

But its not triggering, where am i going wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event doesn't get fired if you have the loop option on, which it is in this case you are presenting.

Comment: See i knew it was something stupid. thank you @Yousef